# How to solve this SQL query in a shorter way?

Tags: sql, database, derby

I have 2 tables, Customer and Trans.

```
Customer
---------
c_id | cName | cSurname | cPbx | cGsm | cLastVisitDate

Trans
------
t_id | c_id | tDate | tPaymentAmount | tSaleAmount
```

I want to select the customers who has a debt greater than zero and hasn't made a transaction since a given date.

For example "List the customer who has a debt and hasn't visited since 20.01.2012"

This is how i tried to solve but it doesn't work.

```
select Customer.c_id, SUM (saleAmount - paymentAmount) as totalDebt, 
cLastVisitDate, 
cName, 
cSurName, 
cPbx, 
cGsm 
from Customer, Trans 
where customer.c_id = trans.c_id AND cLastVisitDate < ?
```

This gives the following error.

> 'CUSTOMER.C_ID' is invalid. When the SELECT list contains at least one
>   aggregate then all entries must be valid aggregate expressions.

I found a solution for this as well which is grouping the query with non-aggregate columns `cLastVisitDate cName cSurname cPbx cGsm` .

```
 select Customer.c_id, SUM (saleAmount - paymentAmount) as totalDebt, 
    cLastVisitDate, 
    cName, 
    cSurName, 
    cPbx, 
    cGsm 
    from Customer, Trans 
    where customer.c_id = trans.c_id AND cLastVisitDate < ?
    group by customer.c_id, cLastVisitDate cName cSurname cPbx cGsm
```

This solution works but it didn't seem the elegant way to do it.Is there a more elegant and simpler way to do this task?

Comment: What's not elegant about it. I can't imagine an equivalent query that's going to be much more readable than that.

Comment: Grouping with all the non-aggregate columns didn't look like the best way to do it.

Comment: I think you also need to group by the customer.c_id field. To my knowledge, all non-aggregated columns that appear in the query need to be grouped by, it is the usual way to perform it. A way to simplify the group-by code (but complicating it in another part) is to encapsulate the aggregated function inside a sub-query. Then you can use the result of the aggregated function as a new column.

Comment: @Miquel, yes you are right.I just forgot to add it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest using a join statement.  It makes your intentions clearer. I'm assuming each customer has one ID, c_id. That means that we can group the transactions by the customer IDs.

```
SELECT c_id, SUM (tSaleAmount - tPaymentAmount) AS totalDebt
FROM Trans
GROUP BY c_id
```

We now have a table with two columns, the customer ID and the customer's total debt.  However, you also want to include the customer information.  This information is contained in the Customer table with an associate customer ID.  This means we can join these two tables on the ID.

```
SELECT Customer.c_id, cName, cSurname, cPbx, cGsm, cLastVisitDate, totalDebt
FROM Customer
JOIN 
   (SELECT c_id, SUM (tSaleAmount - tPaymentAmount) AS totalDebt
    FROM Trans
    GROUP BY c_id) Trans
ON Customer.c_id = Trans.c_id
WHERE totalDebt > 0 AND cLastVisitDate < ?
```

We name the table returned by the SELECT statement by following the statement with the name Trans. We also add in the WHERE clause since we want to return only customers who have debt and haven't visited since a given date.